# MySQL - count with coalesce and add missing rows

Tags: mysql

I have one tables with two date columns (Date_open and Date_closed). All I want to do it to count occurrences per day. So to see how many were opened and closed each day. We look at the last 7 days from today. The problem is that some dates are not present in either of the columns and I can not find a way to either link tables with sub query **(example code 1)** or get coalesce work **(example code 2)**?

The table looks like that:

```
+------+------------+-------------+------+
| code | Date_open  | Date_closed | Prio |
+------+------------+-------------+------+
|    1 | 2018-01-08 | 2018-01-08  | A    |
|    2 | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-08  | B    |
|    3 | 2018-01-06 | 2018-01-07  | C    |
|    4 | 2018-01-06 | 2018-01-06  | A    |
|    5 | 2018-01-04 | 2018-01-06  | B    |
|    6 | 2018-01-03 | 2018-01-01  | C    |
|    7 | 2018-01-03 | 2018-01-02  | C    |
|    8 | 2018-01-03 | 2018-01-02  | C    |
+------+------------+-------------+------+
```

And the results I want are as follows:

```
Date        OpenNo  CloseNo
2018-01-01     1      1
2018-01-02            2
2018-01-03     3    
2018-01-04     1    
2018-01-05      
2018-01-06     2      2
2018-01-07            1
2018-01-08     1      2
```

The first code I tried was:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT t1.Date_open,
COUNT(t1.Date_open) AS 'OpenNo'
FROM
Tbl AS t1
GROUP BY t1.Date_open)
AS A
JOIN
(SELECT t2.Date_closed,
COUNT(t2.Date_closed) AS 'CloseNo'
FROM
Tbl AS t2
GROUP BY t2.Date_closed)
AS B ON A.Date_open = B.Date_closed;
```

This code works as long as there is data for each day.

The second code I tried was:

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE (Date_open, Date_closed) AS Date1,
  COUNT(Date_closed) AS ClosedNo, 
  COUNT(Date_open) AS OpenNo

FROM tbl
GROUP BY Date1;
```

Both do not work. Any ideas please?

Below is the code to create tbl.

```
create table Tbl(
        code int(10) primary key,
        Date_open DATE not null,
        Date_closed DATE not null,
    Prio varchar(10));


insert into Tbl values (1,'2018-01-08','2018-01-08' ,'A');
insert into Tbl values (2,'2018-01-01','2018-01-08' ,'B');
insert into Tbl values (3,'2018-01-06','2018-01-07' ,'C');
insert into Tbl values (4,'2018-01-06','2018-01-06' ,'A');
insert into Tbl values (5,'2018-01-04','2018-01-06' ,'B');
insert into Tbl values (6,'2018-01-03','2018-01-01' ,'C');
insert into Tbl values (7,'2018-01-03','2018-01-02' ,'C');
insert into Tbl values (8,'2018-01-03','2018-01-02' ,'C');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a calendar table, and then left join to your current table twice to generate the counts for each date:

```
SELECT
    d.dt,
    COALESCE(t1.open_cnt, 0) AS OpenNo,
    COALESCE(t2.closed_cnt, 0) AS CloseNo
FROM
(
    SELECT '2018-01-01' AS dt UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-01-02' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-01-03' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-01-04' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-01-05' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-01-06' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-01-07' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-01-08'
) d
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT Date_open, COUNT(*) AS open_cnt
    FROM Tbl
    GROUP BY Date_open
) t1
    ON d.dt = t1.Date_open
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT Date_closed, COUNT(*) AS closed_cnt
    FROM Tbl
    GROUP BY Date_closed
) t2
    ON d.dt = t2.Date_closed
GROUP BY
    d.dt
ORDER BY
    d.dt;
```

### Demo

The reason I aggregate the open and closed date counts in separate subqueries is that if were to try to just do a straight join across all tables involved, we would have to deal with double counting.

**Edit:**

If you wanted to just use the current date and seven days immediately preceding it, then here is a CTE which would do that:

```
WITH dates (
    SELECT CURDATE() AS dt UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY) UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 DAY) UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 DAY) UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 DAY) UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
)
```

You could inline the above into my original query which is aliased as `d`, and it should work.

Comment: Hi Tim, I am afraid I must start my code with SELECT. It is the environment I work in requirements? Also, it needs to be dynamic so the dates are always last 7 days.

Comment: @Kalenji Please check the demo, which is for MySQL 5.6.  I used a CTE in my answer, but you don't have to if you can't/don't want to.

Comment: I have checked it and I am afraid I am restricted and can not create any other tables and I must start my code with SELECT.

Comment: I just updated my answer to inline the dates calendar table.  Now it has no dependence on creating any new tables.

Comment: Impressive code! Thank you. Any idea how to change each select to have dynamic last 7 days?

Comment: I gave you an option to do this.  By the way, I won't add anything else to my answer, because I have already answered your original question.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Coalesce can be confusing - it returns the first non-null value from the list you provide to it.

I don't know if this question requires a super-complex answer.

To get the count of open and closed for each unique date, the following could work.

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE (Date_open, Date_closed) AS Date1,
  SUM(IF(Date_closed != null,1,0)) AS ClosedNo, 
  SUM(IF(Date_open != null,1,0)) AS OpenNo

FROM tbl
GROUP BY Date1;
```

Comment: This by itself won't work, because the original data set may be entirely missing certain dates (e.g. `2018-01-05` does not appear anywhere), yet these dates are expected to appear in the output.

Comment: Yeah if all dates must be accounted for then it's not enough agreed.

Comment: Hi John, The code gives zeros and do not add missing dates. Bear in mind that the data range is always today to -7d.